# What is the curl error 52 “empty reply from server” in LINKEDIN?

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to upload an image to my personal page through the new v2 LinkedIn API.

I am using curl request as shown below :

```
curl -i --upload-file ~/Desktop/Myimage.jpg -H 'Authorization: Bearer Redacted' "https://api.linkedin.com/mediaUpload/C5522AQHn46pwH96hxQ/feedshare-uploadedImage/0?ca=vector_feedshare&cn=uploads&m=AQLKRJOn_yNw6wAAAW2T0DWnRStny4dzsNVJjlF3aN4-H3ZR9Div77kKoQ&app=1983914&sync=0&v=beta&ut=1Dnjy796bpjEY1"
```

After hitting this command on the terminal , I am getting the response: "52 “empty reply from server”.
Please suggest how to resolve this error or what should I use in PHP to upload assets in Linkedin instead of curl?